# Как законнектиться к Telegram Api в iOS приложении?

Tags: ios, telegram, request

Есть цель написать iOS клиент для telegram. Но не могу понять, как начать работать с методами описанными в Api. Сгенерировал приложение с ap_id, api_hash  и др. Я так понимаю коннектиться нужно Available MTProto servers
Test configuration: ......

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сформировать первый любой запрос?

Comment: Есть клиенты с открытым исходным кодом, например, https://github.com/zhukov/webogram попробуйте добавить к ним интересующую вас функциональность, ошибки поправить, чтобы освоиться.

Comment: @jfs спасибо за подсказку. я видел этот проект, но к сожалению в js не силен. Мне бы хотя бы через например через postman, чтобы получилось отправить первый запрос (пробую этот https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode ). А дальше я бы уже разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Телеграмм использует собственный протокол MTProto, первым делом его нужно реализовать. Есть готовое решение для iOS - MTProtoKit, но лично я не нашел к нему документации. Можешь покопаться в исходниках телеграмма. 
После реализации протокола можешь отправлять запросы к апи. Первым делом нужно получить ключ авторизации https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/auth_key.

С запросами к апи не все так просто как, например, с вк апи. Запрос к апи телеграмма есть вызов удаленной процедуры или RPC. Чтобы формировать эти запросы нужно сгенерировать классы TL объектов из TL-схемы. Все запросы сериализуются в массив байт и отправляются в дата центр. Дата центр в свою очередь возвращает ответ.

P.S.
Мог напутать немного, сам только начинаю разбираться.